# Can I use three 2x8 beams instead of two 2x10s for a deck?

Tags: deck

Can I have 3(2x8) beam/girder with 2x10 joists 12" OC? I'm building a 16x16 ledger mounted deck. Two footings were poured a little higher than they should be. There are four 16" footings of 5,000 psi concrete supporting 6x6 posts.

Comment: Why can't the posts be shortened?

Comment: Typically beams need to be the same height as the joists unless you have special hangers designed for the job.

Comment: One of the four 16" was poured 1.5 inch too high

Comment: So you said. It's normal for footings to be slightly out of level, as concrete is more difficult to set precisely than framing. Again, why can't the post be shortened?

Answer (score 4):

Reference the [American Wood Council's Residential Wood Deck Construction Guide free download pdf](https://www.awc.org/pdf/codes-standards/publications/dca/AWC-DCA62015-DeckGuide-1804.pdf).

It looks like 3 2x8 beams allow a longer joist span than 2 2x10s.